# How to save PDF to server?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to modify current code so the pdf output i get when i generate label is **also saved in server**. I have 2 functions which are related to generating pdf and allowing me to save it to local machine. Data is taken from 3rd party source.

```
private function print_order_parcel_label( $tracking_number = null ) 
{
    $label_size = get_option( 'dpd_label_size' );


    $response = self::http_client( 'parcelPrint_', [
        'parcels'     => $tracking_number,
        'printType'   => 'PDF',
        'printFormat' => $label_size ? $label_size : 'A4'
    ] );

    $json_response = json_decode( $response );

    if ( $json_response && $json_response->status == 'err' ) {
        return null;
    } else {
     // echo $response;
        $this->get_labels_output( $response );

        
    }
}

private function get_labels_output( $pdf, $file_name = 'dpdLabels' ) {
    $name = $file_name . '-' . date( 'Y-m-d' ) . '.pdf';

    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/pdf' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"' );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
    header( 'Connection: Keep-Alive' );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
    header( 'Pragma: public' );

    echo $pdf;

    die;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your get_labels_output function you can add before the "die"

```
file_put_contents('../pathToSaveYourPdfFiles/'.$name, $pdf);
```